# How to import .bacpac to Azure Sql Database (not Sql Azure!)

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, ssms

I've created a 2GB Azure SQL Database instance and I want to import my local database to it. When I connect via SSMS to my Azure DB and attempt to Import Data-tier Application from the context menu it wants me to create a new instance on SQL Azure, which isn't what I want..?

How can I import my current database from my local machine to the Azure SQL Database one?

Comment: Not sure if you knew this, but SQL Azure is the same thing as Azure SQL Database. It was renamed a while back. Perhaps you're running an old version of SSMS which has the old name?

Comment: I knew they were renamed. What confuses me though is that SSMS gives me the option to import my backpack file to a new 1GB "Web" SQL Azure database. What I created in the management portal was a 2GB "Basic" Azure SQL Database. Everywhere seems to refer to SQL Azure as being retired so I figured I ought not be using it? I'm using SSMS 2012 btw :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, realized that this was asked a while ago, but since I bumped into the problem myself the other day...

The way to do it now is to place the bacpac file in Azure Blob Storage (using f.ex. Visual Studio). Then use the Import function on the database server from portal.azure.com. The database is created as part of this process, and you can also choose the size.

If the db is large, choose something powerful for a start, so that the import doesn't take ages...

Answer (score -2):

SSMS does not support directly importing from a database. You will need to export your database to a bacpac and then import the bacpac to your Microsoft Azure SQL database.

Comment: Hi - that's what I'd like to know how to do. I've created a bacpac file, connected to my database through SSMS 2012 but when I attempt to import the bacpac file I only have the options to import it as a new SQL Azure "Web or "Business" database. Since SQL Azure is retired and I've already created a 2GB "Basic" Azure SQL Database, how can I got my data in there?

Comment: The answer is basically saying "yes, you can" without actually giving any pointers as to how to do it.